# update fails with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update the field "Vendor No_" of table "Item" according to the most recent entry in "Item Ledger Entry" table, in field "Source No_"

So the "Source No_" most recent record need to be with "Entry Type=0", "Posting Date" with year >= 2018

```
UPDATE  i
    SET i.[Vendor No_] = (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Source No_]
        FROM [MR$Item Ledger Entry] ile
        WHERE i.[No_]=ile.[Item No_] and ile.[Source No_] is not null and i.[Vendor No_] is not null
        ORDER BY ile.[Posting Date] DESC
    )
FROM [MR$Item] i
```

The query returns the error

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Vendor No_', table 'Loja-MR.dbo.MR$Item'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

But if I try to check for "Vendor No_" (Item) null entries I don't have any.. The same aplys to "Source No_" (Item Ledger Entry)

```
select * from [MR$Item]
where [MR$Item].[Vendor No_] is null
```

returns 0 rows

```
select * from [MR$Item Ledger Entry
where [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Source No_] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no *rows*.  Use `cross apply` instead:

```
UPDATE  i
    SET i.[Vendor No_] = ile.[Source No_]
FROM [MR$Item] i CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 [Source No_]
      FROM [MR$Item Ledger Entry] ile
      WHERE i.[No_]=ile.[Item No_] and ile.[Source No_] is not null and i.[Vendor No_] is not null
     ORDER BY ile.[Posting Date] DESC
    ) ile
```

Comment: It worked, but now I need to get sure this query really works and how many records it will afect like use a explain i don't know